# Display value row into column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table with these sample records:

```
CREATE TABLE USERROLES(User ID int,ApplicationID int,Roleid INT) 

INSERT INTO USERROLES
VALUES (11, 1, 1), (11, 1, 5), (11, 3, 5);
```

I want to display below output.

```
USERID  ApplicationID   Roles
-----------------------------
11         1             1,5
11         3              5
```

ApplicationID=1 is duplicates for ROLES 1,5.So it should display in single row.
I am using SQL Server 2016

Comment: You may read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `STUFF` with `FOR XML` let `Roleid` combine.

```
 SELECT 
  UserID,
  ApplicationID,
  STUFF((
    SELECT ',' + cast(Roleid as varchar(max))
    FROM USERROLES tt
    WHERE ApplicationID = t1.ApplicationID
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')
  ,1,1,'') AS Roles
FROM USERROLES t1
group by 
  UserID,
  ApplicationID
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=31474437bcd2fda373dfac3bfee037a0)

**Result**

```
serID   ApplicationID   Roles
11       1              1,5
11       3              5
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below query

```
    SELECT DISTINCT UserID, ApplicationID, Roles = 
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(Roleid as Varchar)
           FROM userroles b 
           WHERE b.UserID = a.UserID and a.ApplicationID = b.ApplicationID 
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM userroles a
GROUP BY UserID, ApplicationID, Roleid
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sometime adding other string with comma add extra space between both, so use
FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
```

instead of

```
 FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
```

as shown below and remove space after comma like ','

```
SELECT DISTINCT UserID, ApplicationID, Roles = 
    STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(Roleid as Varchar)
           FROM userroles b 
           WHERE b.UserID = a.UserID and a.ApplicationID = b.ApplicationID 
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM userroles a
GROUP BY UserID, ApplicationID, Roleid
```